# Does the Noctua NH-U12-DX 1366 cooling system mount on Asus P6T 1366?

Tags: computer-building, cooling

The Noctua NH-U12-DX 1366 is an aftermarket CPU cooler for LGA1366 Xeon CPUs.

On [Noctua's site](http://www.noctua.at/main.php?show=productview&products_id=28&lng=en) they state:

> Caution: The NH-U12DX 1366 can only be
>   used on mainboards that have a
>   backplate with screw threads for CPU
>   cooler installation (such as the Intel
>   reference backplate for Xeon 5500).
>   The cooler is thus incompatible with
>   Xeon 3500 and Core i7 mainboards that
>   don’t have such a backplate.

How do I know if the Asus P6T has this backplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered this on my own. It is not compatible; buy the Noctua NH-U12-P for 1366 desktop instead.